# "non-numeric argument to binary operator" when using fct_lump()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to find out whether the proportion of `Granted` loans varies across`ZipCode`s in the state of Alabama. My data is called `LoanApps`, and I am trying to use the function `fct_lump` to lump together the 30 most common zip codes to use on a bar plot (as there are too many zip codes to plot at once)

My error message is:
"Error in fct_lump(LoanApps$ZipCode, 30) + ggplot(data = LoanApps) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "+.gg") for "+""

```
# A tibble: 169,256 x 7
   Granted Amount Title                   Debt2IncomeRatio ZipCode State EmploymentYears
   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>                              <dbl> <chr>   <chr> <fct>          
 1 No        5000 Debt consolidation                100    368xx   AL    < 1            
 2 No       22000 Debt consolidation                100    357xx   AL    < 1            
 3 No        2500 Other                             100    350xx   AL    < 1            
 4 No       27000 Debt consolidation                100    354xx   AL    < 1            
 5 No        4500 Other                             100    368xx   AL    < 1            
 6 No       10000 Debt consolidation                100    365xx   AL    < 1            
 7 No       10000 Credit card refinancing           100    365xx   AL    < 1            
 8 No       10000 Other                             100    354xx   AL    < 1            
 9 No        3500 Major purchase                      0.95 352xx   AL    < 1            
10 No       15000 Other                              15.4  356xx   AL    < 1            
# ... with 169,246 more rows
```

```
ggplot(data = LoanApps) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = ZipCode, fill = Granted)) +
  fct_lump(LoanApps$ZipCode, 30) +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: You're mixing data manipulation with plot creation. Manipulate your data first (`fct_lump)`, then plot `ggplot()`.

Comment: I have tried that but still get the same error message

Comment: Well, please show what you tried in the question. (That is, using `fct_lump` on the data, not adding it to the plot.)

Comment: ```fct_lump(LoanApps$ZipCode, 30) +
  ggplot(data = LoanApps) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = ZipCode, fill = Granted)) +
  coord_flip()```

Comment: You can't add with `+` data to a plot. You can only add `ggplot2` function results, like geoms, coords, scales, themes. Modify the data first, e.g., `LoanApps$ZipCode = fct_lump(LoanApps$ZipCode, 30)`. Then plot the data: `ggplot(data = LoanApps) + ...`.

Comment: *If* you're using `dplyr`, you can use pipes `%>%` to modify the data and give it to `ggplot`, e.g., `LoansApp %>% mutate(ZipCode = fct_lump(ZipCode, 30)) %>% ggplot() + geom_bar...`. But I would recommend keeping it simple as in my comment above. Do the data manipuation in one step. Actually modify the data frame. Then, in another statement, plot it.

Comment: Thank you! I modified it first as you suggested and that worked perfectly for me.